# Does reaching 5K break my rejected edits stats?

Tags: bug, review-queues, suggested-edits

I'm not sure that this is the cause, but I've recently reached 5K rep and gained the "approve tag wiki edits" privilege.  I noticed today, that when I look at one of my reviews for an [edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8210837), and click on the more, it is showing that I have approved 399 edits and rejected 1.  The approved looks about right, but the rejected isn't even close to being true.  I'm pretty sure that last time I checked, I had rejected over 600 edits (I tend to skip lots of edits and focus on the ones that should be rejected).

Is it possible that gaining the CW edit privilege has reset the counter, or is something else going on that I haven't noticed?